# Allow other information to be included with any type of comment flag

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

Occasionally when I see a big long thread of obsolete-chatty-argument comments, I'll just flag one of them, select "other..." as the reason, and just request that the whole thread be deleted (rather than creating a dozen flags).

Maybe I'm doing it wrong and should just make all the flags (should I?), but [here's another case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285872/can-reviewers-view-edits-made-within-the-5-minute-grace-period?cb=1) in which an "obsolete" flag was rejected (as an example of this being useful on things other than long chains). Perhaps a brief clarification could have helped.

I envisage something like this, where the text area can be empty if it's anything other than "other...".

[image]

Comment: The comment flag handling system is generic enough that I'm not sure this would benefit anyone. I agree that it could be nice, and it'd probably be good for reporting (whether that matters or not, I don't know), but I'd say a perfectly reasonable workaround is what you're doing. If you need an explanation, use "other," and incorporate both, like "Obsolete; This comment was incorporated into the answer." That would probably have the result for mods UI-wise as any first-class support.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's an ambiguity as to the point at which the conversation went south, just flag the question or answer with a custom flag.

All the information that the moderator needs to know will be in one convenient spot, and there's no need to clutter the UI any further.  Moderators also have the ability to clear all of the comments at once, if the need arises, and that button is associated with the post, not the individual comments.

Answer (score 3):

If the whole comment thread needs to be deleted, flag the question/answer, and provide a custom reason. If only a few comments need to be removed, you can use a custom reason like,

> Comments #3,4,5, and 7 are obsolete

or similar. Don't flag each individual comment. That makes it hard for the moderators to take care of.

When only 2-3 comments are obsolete (due to an edit or whatever), I'll often flag the first one with something like:

> This and the next 2 comments are obsolete

---

I don't see why you would need a comment box for every flag reason. If it seems at all questionable, or would be clearer with an explanation, use the 'other' flag. For instance, when someone asked me to add something to my answer, and it landed in the grace period, I'd use something like:

[image]

I don't see a reason why your proposal would hurt (other than obstructing more area - minor), but I also don't really see a need for it at all.