# Why am I getting the message "An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA' all the time now?

Tags: support, answers, captcha, error-message

When I try to post an answer on MSE, this box comes up (as usual):

[image]

So I check the box and complete the CAPTCHA:

[image]

When I try to submit it, this error comes up:

[image]

<sup>*click any image for full size*</sup>

I haven't been able to post answers for about 2 days.

I tried logging out, and back in. Same issue. I tried restarting my router (had it off for about 10 minutes), nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried a different PC?

Comment: Not yet. I'll try it.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try passing Captcha by moving your mouse around after checking the box (so that it doesn't come to typing in the letters).

Comment: @Mooseman, That worked. typed some characters and posted as answer from laptop, then copied/pasted test answer on this computer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248442/allow-other-information-to-be-included-with-any-type-of-comment-flag/248490#248490

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the fact that posting an answer [worked from another computer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248489/why-am-i-getting-the-message-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-captcha-all-the?noredirect=1#comment813845_248489), I'm going to say the following:

**Clear your cookies, cache, etc.**

Answer (score 1):

Opening developer console(Ctrl+Shift+I) in Chrome, checking Network->Disable cache and refreshing the page helped me.